# ASP.NET Core model binder result logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I would like to increase / improve my logging.

So far I had in each controller action code like

```
  public asyc Task<IActionResult> Action1(int id, [FromBody] RequestModel request) {
    string log = $"{nameof(Action1)}(id: {id}, request: {request?.ToJson()})";
    _logger.LogInformation(log);
```

The main purpose was to see whats actually reaching the controller action.

I removed it since it cluttered the code heavily (e.g. for methods with a lot of paramters). But now I am unhappy with the result that the logs do not show the information any more (and I needed them to investigate some unexplainable bugs).

Is there a way to hook up into the model binder result (e.g. via a service filter) to log the model binder result?

---

Works like charm: thanks to Shahzad Hassan

```
  public class MethodCallParameterLogger : IAsyncActionFilter
  {

    public ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; }

    public MethodCallParameterLogger(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      LoggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {

      LoggerFactory

        // the display name contains the controller name space, controller name, method name and the postfix " (ActionLogger)"
        .CreateLogger(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0])

        // MIND THAT THIS LOGS EVEN SENSITIVE DATA (e.g. credentials) !!!
        .LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.ActionArguments));

      var resultContext = await next();

    }

  }
```

Comment: Model binder would probably be a bad idea, but you could do it with an attribute.

Comment: Well, model binder was the first thing that came to my mind since it produces what I want to log. Any hints into a direction. I am in the dark and it seems you have a clue what I am looking for. :-)

Comment: Can't show anything right now, got a new laptop and it's not set up yet. Of course, logging all parameters is a huge security hole, not something I would allow my devs to do.

Comment: Better than logging the full request bodies :-) Yah, for sure, in the code sample avove the ToJson() took care of blanking sensitive data. Once I figured out how to hook into the process I am thinking about an SensitiveAttribute which my logging code respects and blanks those values. But one step after the other. And of course it's just for testing machines. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use an ActionFilter instead. ActionFilters are executed after the model binding, so you can retrieve the parameters from the `ActionExecutingContext`. You can override the `OnActionExecuting` method and log whatever is required:

```
public class LogParamsFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<LogsParamsFilter> _logger;

    public LogParamsFilter (ILogger<LogsParamsFilter> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var id = (int)context.ActionArguments["id"];
        var request = context.ActionArguments["request"] as RequestModel;
        var action = context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName;

        string log = $"{action)}(id: {id}, request: {request?.ToJson()})";
        _logger.LogInformation(log);

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

You would need to use it as [TypeFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typefilterattribute) on the controller action so that its dependencies i.e. ILogger is resolved via DI.

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(LogParamsFilter))]
public asyc Task<IActionResult> Action1(int id, [FromBody] RequestModel request)
{
    ...
}
```

Or you can register it globally in the startup for all controllers:

```
services.AddMvc(options => options
    .Filters.Add(new TypeFilterAttribute(typeof(LogParamsFilter))));
```

In order to use it as a generic filter for all controller actions, iterate through the `context.ActionArguments.Keys` property and log the value for each key. You would need to do some type checkings and call `.ToJson()` if the type of the `ActionArgument` is RequestModel.

I hope that helps.